# Problem with Magento 2 installation and JS/CSS files

Tags: magento2, installation

I have been having problems with getting Magento2 installed on LAMP CentOS VPS.

I setup everything via terminal on a Mac, logged in as the web account user, so ownership should be fine.

I have installed composer, and that is how I have installed Magento.

I cloned it from here: git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2.git

Installed via composer: composer install

Updated via composer: composer update

Ran the installer via visiting the domain and running through each section, which went through fine.

On visiting the site (front end) i get lots of 404 errors on /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma etc etc.

So i run the suggested permissions:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Which then give me this error: You don't have permission to access / on this server.

OK...

So i try different permissions:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Which then returns lots of 404 errors on /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma etc etc again

Where am i going wrong?

I have scrapped and tried to reinstall around about 100 times. I've tried every tutorial, read every documentation i can find. Can anyone shed any light on this and why I am having so many issues?

Have i missed an important step of the installation or something?

Comment: Is there any content in /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma? Try `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

R.S is right, you should run and run

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and try this

```
chmod -R 777 pub
```

from your magento root to make sure it has writing permissions. Magento should generate static files on every request when in developer mode, so it might be a problem with permissions.